# Atajo de teclado para hacer focus en menú lateral izquierdo en VSC

Tags: vscode

Me gustaría saber si hay algún modo de acceder al menú lateral izquierdo de VSC con el teclado para poder desplazarme por el sin necesidad de usar el ratón. Se que se abre con Ctrl+B pero haciendo esto no se logra hacer focus en él. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te refieres al arbol de archivos o a los botones de Files, Search, Extensions etc?

Comment: Al árbol de archivos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con **Ctrl+Shift+f** Abre el buscador de archivos.

Con **Ctrol+Shift+e**  Abre el explorador, te posiciona en el árbol de archivos.

Una vez en el arbol si se abre un archivo ya queda haciendo foco dentro del archivo para editar. Para hacerlo se debe desplazar entre archivos con las **flechas de dirección arriba y abajo**, finalmente para confirmar se presiona **Enter**.

Si se está navegando entre el panel y se desea volver al archivo del lado derecho se debe volver al árbol y si se presiona nuevamente **Con Ctrol+Shift+e** se vuelve a poner el foco en el lado derecho.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, es justo lo que estaba buscando, no lo encontré en el listado de métodos abreviados de teclado. Mil gracias!!!!

Comment: Me alegra mucho que te haya servido, quedo a las órdenes.